# Seekbar increase value upto 100

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, seekbar

I have a seek bar with max=25. what i want to do is when user drags the seekbar to max value and it is in pressed state than after reaching the maximum value seekbar still continuous incrementing i.e. 26,27,28,.... 100. (if seek bar is pressed)

I tried two ways using loops and also threads but they didn't work.

I have a text view on which i am showing the value of progress,

here is the code.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
         float p_prog = (float) (progress/10.0);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (seekBar.getId()) {
        case R.id.seekbar_bar:

            fat_count = p_prog;
            if (p_prog == 0) {

                txt_Fat.setBackgroundDrawable(res
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.fat_at_null));
                txt_Fat.setText(p_prog + "g   ");

                first_plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                first_plus.setAnimation(null);
            } else if (p_prog > 0 && p_prog < 3) {
                txt_Fat.setBackgroundDrawable(res
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.fat_green));
                txt_bottom_description.setText("Fat started");
                txt_Fat.setText(p_prog + "g   ");

            } else if (p_prog > 3 && p_prog < 20) {
                txt_Fat.setBackgroundDrawable(res
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.fat_yellow));
                first_plus.setAnimation(null);
                first_plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt_Fat.setText(p_prog + "g   ");

            } else if (p_prog >= 20) {

                txt_Fat.setBackgroundDrawable(res
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.fat_red));
                first_plus.setVisibility(1);
                first_plus.startAnimation(anim);
                txt_Fat.setText(p_prog+"g   ");

                if(s_Fat.isPressed() && p_prog >24){
                    for(float z=p_prog; z<100;z++){
                        txt_Fat.setText(z+"g   ");
                    }
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the xml attribute `android:max` like

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbartest"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="25"/>
```

Refer the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android%3amax)

Comment: i have already set this value. i want to increment the value after it reaches the max value 25. and the seekbar is in pressed state like i did..  if(s_Fat.isPressed() && p_prog >24)

Comment: yes i am not getting more than 25 . when it reaches to max (25) i want to increment/increase it to 100 and also when it is in pressed state.

Comment: Then why you define the max as 25?? Also how you are determining the pressed state??

Comment: i define it because when user moves the seekbar and reaches 20 than if the progress is greater than 20 the background of textview will turns to red. and when it reaches to 25 which is the end it should keep increasing the value in text view. which shows user that the seekbar is reached to maximum value but the value is contiuously incrementing

Comment: How you are determining the pressed state?? Are you capturing the onClick of seekbar?? If so, you can move the check inside onClick itself.

Comment: i am using isPressed() method which ensures that the seekbar is pressed

Comment: I'm still not getting it right. Let me try one more time. The problem is you are not getting value after 25 in the text box or you are getting value till 100 if the seek bar is pressed. Kindly be clear.

Comment: i want that the user will move the seekbar to max than the red color of text view means that he have reached the maximum value. Now the user don't know that 25 is last value. so i want that user when takes it to maximum value than he have still pressed the seekbar. At this state i want that the text view to show the value must keep increment i.e to 26,27,28...100 (when user have pressed the seekbar &  value of progress bar reached to max value) and text view is still incrementing i want to show the text view showing the value is still incrementing after reaching the maximum value

Comment: I am not getting value till 100. i need value upto 100 when user reaches 25. than the text view should starts incrementing to 26,27, upto 100.